# Can a Object have method or variable which is not define in a class?

Tags: java, class, oop, object, instance

I know it’s stupid to ask but I want to make sure.In object oriented language, Is there any situation or chance that a object created from a particular class can have a method or variable which is not define in that class?

Comment: Yes. It may have properties inherited from superclasses. And some bytecode manipulation program can monkey-patch it after compilation too.

Comment: There are child and parent classes in java.Every class you have created is inherited from the main parent class - Object.You don't type manually that your class is extended the Object class.To check what I have said , create any class and see all available methods - you will see the methods of your class and the Object class.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to have Variables and Methods in a Class which are not directly defined in it. This happens when you have an abstract class and a child class (a class which extends the abstract class).

It is actually a very common approach when it comes to OOP to have a much better reusability of your Codebase.

Imagine you have an abstract class called **Vehicle** which looks like this:

```
public abstract class Vehicle {

protected enum Condition {
    BAD,
    OK,
    GOOD
}

private int numOfWheels;
private int numOfSeats;
private boolean isDriving;
private boolean isMotorized;
private Condition condition;

public Vehicle(int numOfWheels,
               int numOfSeats,
               boolean isDriving,
               boolean isMotorized,
               Condition condition) {
    this.numOfWheels = numOfWheels;
    this.numOfSeats = numOfSeats;
    this.isDriving = isDriving;
    this.isMotorized = isMotorized;
    this.condition = condition;
}

protected void repair() {
    if(!this.condition.equals(Condition.GOOD)) {
        this.condition = Condition.GOOD;
    }
}
```

Then you have a child class called **Car** which could look something like this:

```
public class Car extends Vehicle {
private String brand;
private String model;

public Car(int numOfSeats,
           boolean isDriving,
           Condition condition,
           String brand,
           String model) {
    super(4, numOfSeats, isDriving, true, condition);
    this.brand = brand;
    this.model = model;
}
```

The Constructor in your Car class first calls the super Constructor in your parent class with the given parameters and then sets the specific variables for your Car Object.

You can then call your Car construcor with something like this:

```
Car car = new Car(2, false, Vehicle.Condition.BAD, "Mercedes", "AMG");
```

So if you want to call the repair Method now, which is defined in your abstract class Vehicle, you can simply do this call:

```
car.repair();
```

What we have achieved with this Architecture is that everytime we want to create an Object which is a Vehicle like a Bicycle for example, we only have to declare some specific variables or Methods like we did in the Car class and not the same over and over again.

In much bigger Projects this can save you a lot of work and make your life easier.

I hope my explanation could help you understand the principle of OOP.